# Enable/Disable Generation of Serialisation Assembly in MsBuild

Tags: performance, visual-studio, serialization

How does it Impact performance when my application is running to Enable/Disable Generation of Serialisation Assemblies in Visual Studio's Build Properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSBuild will run the `SGen` task when you force serialization assemblies to be generated.  How long that takes entirely depends on the capabilities of your machine and the size of the generated assembly.  A second is a very rough guesstimate.

But don't guess at it, let MSBuild *tell* you how long it took so you know a real number instead of a guess.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Change the MSBuild build output verbosity setting to "Detailed".  MSBuild now displays a breakdown of every task it executed and how long it took:

```
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateBindingRedirects                   1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           1 calls
1>        0 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  MakeDir                                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignCulture                              1 calls
1>        1 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           2 calls
1>        1 ms  FindUnderPath                              5 calls
1>        1 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      1 calls
1>        1 ms  CallTarget                                 1 calls
1>        1 ms  Delete                                     2 calls
1>        1 ms  AssignTargetPath                           6 calls
1>        2 ms  Copy                                       2 calls
1>        2 ms  Message                                    3 calls
1>       10 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
1>       83 ms  Csc                                        1 calls
1>      541 ms  SGen                                       1 calls // <=== here!
```

Don't assume anything from the numbers I pasted here, be sure to try it on your own machine.

---

After attempted edit, sure.  The very first visitor to your web site is not going to get his page load delayed by that second.  It depends on how often you recycle the site but running sgen is primarily useful for interactive desktop apps, not much for servers that are expected to run for a long time.

Comment: thank you Hans, btw I asked if it impact the performance of the website and not the compilation time, my question was not clear enougth I edit it now.